# How to convert a month number (i.e. "12") into month name in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2016

I've got data in a spreadsheet that's formatted YYYYMM and I need to convert it to Month Year format (i.e. 201406 -> June 2014)

I'm using RIGHT() and LEFT() to pull the corresponding bits from the initial data cells, but I can't figure out how to turn the month number into a month name (i.e. 06 -> June, 01 -> January, etc.)

I've tried `TEXT(RIGHT(B2,2),"mmmm")` which only returns January regardless of the number inputted.

Ideally this should be easy, so, any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DATE([Year],[Month],[Day])` passing any values for year and day. Just note that this will make the actual value of the cell different to 12 though.

Excel will be reading 12 as a date which will be 12 days after 00/01/1900 (this is 0 as a date) returning 12/01/1900 which is in January.

`TEXT(DATE(1,B2,1),"mmmm")`

Comment: Yes, I meant to but it made me wait like 10 minutes or whatever. It's been accepted now.

Answer (score 3):

To make `201406` -> `June 2014`, The `Date()` formula would do pretty good job indeed. This is the whole formula that would make the transition:

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,2),1),"MMMM YYYY")
```

---

Or something hardcoded as this can work:

```
=CHOOSE(B1,"January","February","March","April","May","June","July")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add "01" to the end of your number so you can format it to look like a date, and then return the month from it.

`=Text($A$1 & "01","####-##-##")` will return `2014-06-01`.
`=TEXT("2014-06-01","mmmm yyyy")` will return `June 2014`.

So....

`=TEXT(TEXT($A$1 & "01","####-##-##"),"mmmm yyyy")` returns `June 2014`.